# R tree library + how to run

Tags: java, r

I have a simple question

I want to Run a code of R tree using java netbeans (for testing)

Now I found This library of R tree https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsi/

I was able to add the library. But then what ?? How I Actually Run the queries and the insertion..etc ??

Can anyone please help me with that. I'm a beginner

Please help

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from the file [NearestN.java](https://github.com/aled/jsi-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/jsi/examples/NearestN.java) There is also [Contains.java](https://github.com/aled/jsi-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/jsi/examples/Contains.java)

```
package net.sourceforge.jsi.examples;

import org.slf4j.*;
import com.infomatiq.jsi.*;
import gnu.trove.*;

import com.infomatiq.jsi.Rectangle;
import com.infomatiq.jsi.rtree.RTree;

public class NearestN {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NearestN.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NearestN().run();
  }

  private class NullProc implements TIntProcedure {
    public boolean execute(int i) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  private void run() {
    int rowCount = 1000;
    int columnCount = 1000;
    int count = rowCount * columnCount;
    long start, end;

    log.info("Creating " + count + " rectangles");
    final Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[count];
    int id = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
      for (int column = 0; column < rowCount; column++) {
        rects[id++] = new Rectangle(row, column, row+0.5f, column+0.5f); //
    }

    log.info("Indexing " + count + " rectangles");
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SpatialIndex si = new RTree();
    si.init(null);
    for (id=0; id < count; id++) {
      si.add(rects[id], id);
    }

    final Point p = new Point(36.3f, 84.3f);
    log.info("Querying for the nearest 3 rectangles to " + p);
    si.nearestN(p, new TIntProcedure() {
      public boolean execute(int i) {
        log.info("Rectangle " + i + " " + rects[i] + ", distance=" + rects[i].distance(p));
        return true;
      }
    }, 3, Float.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Hope that can help you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by moskito-x comes from the jsi-examples repo, hosted at github.

You should be able to run the examples with the following commands (on linux):

```
git clone https://github.com/aled/jsi-examples.git
cd jsi-examples
mvn package
cd target
unzip jsi-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
java -cp .:./classes net.sourceforge.jsi.examples.Contains
```

The source code should hopefully be self explanatory.

Aled.