# TIntProcedure cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to use the [Java Spatial Index Library](https://github.com/aled/jsi), but can't get the [examples](https://github.com/aled/jsi-examples) to load.

When I try to open the following file, from the examples, in Eclipse Kepler, Eclipse complains about `TIntProcedure` not being able to be resolved:

```
package net.sourceforge.jsi.examples;

import gnu.trove.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.infomatiq.jsi.Rectangle;
import com.infomatiq.jsi.SpatialIndex;
import com.infomatiq.jsi.rtree.RTree;

public class Contains {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Contains.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Contains().run();
  }

  private void run() {
    // Create and initialize an rtree
    SpatialIndex si = new RTree();
    si.init(null);

    // We have some points or rectangles in some other data structure.
    // The rtree can handle millions of these.
    Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[] {
        new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0),
        new Rectangle(0, 1, 0, 1),
        new Rectangle(1, 0, 1, 0),
        new Rectangle(1, 1, 1, 1),
    };

    // Add our data to the rtree. Every time we add a rectangle we give it
    // an ID. This ID is what is returned by querying the rtree. In this 
    // example we use the array index as the ID.
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
      si.add(rects[i], i);
    }

    // Now see which of these points is contained by some
    // other rectangle. The rtree returns the results of a query
    // by calling the execute() method on a TIntProcedure.
    // In this example we want to save the results of the query 
    // into a list, so that's what the execute() method does.
    class SaveToListProcedure implements TIntProcedure {
      private List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      @Override
      public boolean execute(int id) {
        ids.add(id);
        return true;
      }; 

      private List<Integer> getIds() {
        return ids;
      }
    };

    SaveToListProcedure myProc = new SaveToListProcedure();
    si.contains(new Rectangle(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f), myProc);

    List<Integer> ids = myProc.getIds();

    for (Integer id : ids) {
      log.info(rects[id].toString() + " was contained");
    }

    // Actually that was a really long winded (and inefficient) way of 
    // printing out the rectangles. Would be better to use an anonymous
    // class to just do the printing inside the execute method. That is
    // what the NearestN class does.
  }
}
```

`TIntProcedure` appears to be from the [gnu trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) package, but the `TIntProcedure` interface is actually defined in `gnu.trove.procedure` and not `gnu.trove`.

Am I using the wrong `TIntProcedure`?  Eclipse is fine with the declaration of the `SaveToListProcedure` but shows a warning at the line `si.contains(new Rectangle(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f), myProc)`.  I tried to run the project anyway, just to see if Eclipse was throwing a false error, but it errors out with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at net.sourceforge.jsi.examples.Contains.main(Contains.java:18)
```

Line 18 is where `main` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSI is using Trove 2.0.2. They didn't move TIntProcedure into that package until 3.x. Downgrading the package explicitly worked for me.

Comment: Sorry I missed your answer.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not building with maven, then currently you will need trove4j version 2.0.2. The next version of JSI (version 1.1) will depend on trove 3.0.3 (master branch was updated a while ago).

Also note, detailed instructions for running the jsi examples are available in my answer to this question: [R tree library + how to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251509/r-tree-library-how-to-run)

Aled.